# Passing dynamic input field array item values with different names to php

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I'm using this form from [formvalidation.io](http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/):

```
<form id="bookForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Book</label>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book[0].title" placeholder="Title" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book[0].isbn" placeholder="ISBN" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book[0].price" placeholder="Price" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addButton"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The input field names are very special, e.g. `name="book[0].title"`.

How to pass all these input field array values to my php script?

I guess the `"."` is not php compliant. Changing the names in a way like `name="book[0][title]` leads to error messages like `Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in www/...` with `print_r($_POST['book'][0]['title']);`.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `print_r($_POST[books][0][title]);` instead, hope it helps.
Also, is it 'book' or 'books'? That could bring an error too. But my point is that you don't have to use ' delimiter.

Comment: Sorry for my typo! It is 'book'.

Comment: How to loop this type of input array values in php?

Comment: Something like `foreach($_POST[book] as $myBook){
   ...
}`

Answer (score 1):

Below format should work

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="book[0][title]" placeholder="Title" />
```

When you `print_r($_POST)` you will get the submitted data in proper array format. And you can also get the title by using `$_POST['book'][0]['title']`

```
[book] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => titletext
                    [isbn] => isbntext
                    [price] => 100
                )

        )
```